# Restrict IAM Role to be attached to an EC2 instance if Instance Id does not match the one in IAM Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to create IAM Policy which restricts passing the IAM Role to an EC2 instance that if instance id does not equal to `i-1234567890abcd`

There is no error in the policy but there is no effect of this policy either. If I remove `Condition` from the below policy, it works but it restricts the role to be attached to any EC2 instance.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": ["iam:PassRole"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/MyEC2InstanceSpecificRole"],
      "Condition": {
        "ArnNotEquals": {
          "ec2:SourceInstanceARN": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:000000000000:instance/i-1234567890abcd"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is not possible.

The [Granting a User Permissions to Pass a Role to an AWS Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html) documentation states:

> To pass a role (and its permissions) to an AWS service, a user must have permissions to *pass the role* to the service. This helps administrators ensure that only approved users can configure a service with a role that grants permissions. To allow a user to pass a role to an AWS service, you must grant the `PassRole` permission to the user's IAM user, role, or group.
>
> When a user passes a role ARN as a parameter to any API that uses the role to assign permissions to the service, the service checks whether that user has the `iam:PassRole` permission. To limit the user to passing only approved roles, you can filter the `iam:PassRole` permission with the Resources element of the IAM policy statement.

Also on [Using an IAM Role to Grant Permissions to Applications Running on Amazon EC2 Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html) it states:

> PassRole is not an API action in the same way that RunInstances or ListInstanceProfiles is. Instead, it's a permission that AWS checks whenever a role ARN is passed as a parameter to an API (or the console does this on the user's behalf). It helps an administrator to control which roles can be passed by which users.

The normal use-case for `PassRole` is to ensure that users do not grant AWS Services any more permissions that they should be allowed to use themselves. It tries to avoid a situation where a non-Admin user passes an Admin role to a service with the sinister intention of then using that service to access resources that they would not normally be allowed to access. For example, launching an Amazon EC2 instance with an Admin role, so that they can then login to that instance and issue Admin commands that they would not normally be entitled to use.

The above documentation suggests that the `PassRole` permission is evaluated to confirm their **permission to pass a certain role to a certain *service***, rather than how that service is going to use the role itself (eg by then assigning it to an EC2 instance to generate STS credentials).